# Show only first word of parenthetical citation in BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

[Standard MLA style](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/747/02/) is to display only the first word of a parenthetical citation. For example, a citation of "Encyclopedia Britannica Online Academic Edition" would be displayed only as `(Encyclopedia)`.

I can remove any other authors and the "et al." suffix with

```
\usepackage[maxcitenames=1,uniquename=init,uniquelist=false]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{andothers=\unskip} % delete et al.
```

However, I can't figure out how to prevent a citation such as `\cite{britannica}` from appearing as `(Encyclopedia Britannica Online Academic Edition)`; the desired output would be simply `(Encyclopedia)` (or possibly `(Britannica)`).

How can I accomplish this in BibLaTeX?

Comment: Is `shortauthor = {Britannica}` what you are looking for?

Comment: There is also `shorthand = {Britannica}`/`shorthand = {EB}`.

Comment: @moewe thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. If you post an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex`'s `shortauthor` field can be used to abbreviate long (especially corporate) authors.

The [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) states on p. 30 (§2.3.3 *Corporate Authors and Editors*)

> Corporate authors and editors are given in the `author` or `editor` field,
>   respectively. Note that they must be wrapped in an extra pair of curly
>   braces to prevent data parsing from treating them as personal names
>   which are to be dissected into their components. Use the `shortauthor`
>   field if you want to give an abbreviated form of the name or an
>   acronym for use in citations.

```
author = {{National Aeronautics and Space Administration}},
shortauthor = {NASA},
```

> The default citation
>   styles will use the short name in all citations while the full name is
>   printed in the bibliography.

While on page 21, we find

> `shortauthor` list (name): The author(s) of the work, given in an abbreviated form. This field is
>   mainly intended for abbreviated forms of corporate authors[...].

---

There is also the `shorthand` option, which will not replace the name part of citation, but the whole citation label.

> `shorthand` field (literal): A special designation to be used by the
>   citation style instead of the usual label. This field is intended for
>   citation aliasing. If defined, it overrides the default label.
>   (p. 22 of the documentation)

---

Compare the output for the following `.bib` file (with `authoryear`)

```
@book{EBSH,
  author    = {{Encyclopedia Britannica Shorthand Edition}},
  shorthand = {EB},
  title     = {EB With Shorthand},
  year      = {2014},
  publisher = {Shorthand Press},
  location  = {Global},
}
@book{EBSA,
  author      = {{Encyclopedia Britannica Shortauthor Edition}},
  shortauthor = {Britannica},
  title       = {EB With Shortauthor},
  year        = {2014},
  publisher   = {Shorthand Press},
  location    = {Global},
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{EBSH,
  author    = {{Encyclopedia Britannica Shorthand Edition}},
  shorthand = {EB},
  title     = {EB With Shorthand},
  year      = {2014},
  publisher = {Shorthand Press},
  location  = {Global},
}
@book{EBSA,
  author      = {{Encyclopedia Britannica Shortauthor Edition}},
  shortauthor = {Britannica},
  title       = {EB With Shortauthor},
  year        = {2014},
  publisher   = {Shorthand Press},
  location    = {Global},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{EBSH,EBSA}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]