# Cite Publisher and Date when no author is available - eg. website

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm trying to stick to the author-year-style of citation. Unfortunately I've to cite several webpages with no specific author. In that case BibLaTeX uses the title of an `@online`-entry as next resort.
For the sake of compactness I would like to use the publisher and date instead.

E.g.:
`\parencite{my-bibid}` producing something like

> (A fancy publisher, 2020)

**That's my MWE:**

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, a4paper, titlepage, parskip=half]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}   

\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 


\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, sorting=nyt, giveninits=true,]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
    andothers = {et al.},
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
    @online{my-bibid,
        title       = {This is a title way to long to put in the text as a whole string omg look it's so long it doesn't even stop good help us},
        publisher   = {A fancy Publisher},
        year        = {2020},
        url         = {https://latex.is.super.omg},
        urldate     = {2020-04-18}
    }   
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    I want to cite the publisher and the year \parencite{my-bibid}. <- looks bad

    I want to cite the publisher and the year \citefield{my-bibid}{publisher} \citefield{my-bibid}{year} <- but why?! 


    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I found some great code from @cfr on [Cite publisher in text from BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327973/cite-publisher-in-text-from-biblatex)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand\citepublisher
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}% supplemented from moewe's answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207676/
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}}
  {\printlist{publisher}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {}
```

Unfortunately I didn't manage to also print the year in the same command. 
Oh, and TexStudio won't show me suggestions for the new `\citepublisher` command. Is there a trick?

I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

`\citefield` won't work on `publisher`, because `publisher` is not a normal literal field, it is a list. For lists you have to use `\citelist` instead. That's why [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr)'s `\citepublisher` from [Cite publisher in text from BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/327973/35864) uses `\printlist` and not `\printfield`. If you don't know the type of a field, you can look it up in [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (§2 *Database Guide* > § 2.2 *Entry Fields*).

It is of course possible to change the output of `\parencite` and friends directly by manipulating the relevant bibmacros.

If `authoryear.cbx` can't find an author or editor it prints a replacement label with

```
\newbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \iffieldundef{label}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}}
    {\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{label}}}}
```

You modify this macro to print the publisher if available

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \iffieldundef{label}
      {\iflistundef{publisher}
         {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
         {\printlist{publisher}}}
      {\printfield{label}}}}
```

There is one issue with this approach: Technically speaking **`@online` entries don't have `publisher`s, instead they use `organization`**. You will for example find, that the `publisher` field is not shown in the bibliography at all. Using it in the citation seems risky.

So you *could* use `organization`

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:label}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \iffieldundef{label}
      {\iflistundef{organization}
         {\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
         {\printlist{organization}}}
      {\printfield{label}}}}
```

---

But I would like to suggest two different approaches.

Depending on the exact nature of the real world entry you have in mind, it is a much better idea to

1. Upgrade the publisher to `author` or `editor`. There is no problem in having a 'corporate' author. `author`s don't have to be people. Keep in mind that 'corporate names' with spaces need protection with double braces in name fields (see [Using a 'corporate author' in the "author" field of a bibliographic entry (spelling out the name in full)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864)).

   See also my introductory remarks in my answer to [If no author use organization or institution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480431/35864) or the recent [Why is biblatex defaulting to using title instead of author when no author is provided and how do I change it to using journaltitle instead?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538475/35864).

   If required an abbreviation of the name can be given in the `shortauthor` field: [Show only first word of parenthetical citation in BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/160191/35864).
2. You can use the `label` field to give a replacement label in case `author`, `editor` and `translator` are all missing. It should be mentioned, however, that with `label` Biber does not calculate uniqueness data, so you will not get disambiguation letters after the years if there are two works by the same `label` from the same `year`.

Usually I prefer option 1, but maybe option 2 is better suited to your particular entry.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, a4paper, titlepage, parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, giveninits=true,]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{test:author,
  title       = {This is a title way to long to put in the text as a
                 whole string omg look it's so long it doesn't even
                 stop good help us},
  author      = {{A fancy Publisher}},
  year        = {2020},
  url         = {https://latex.is.super.omg},
  urldate     = {2020-04-18}
}
@online{test:label,
  title       = {This is a title way to long to put in the text as a
                 whole string omg look it's so long it doesn't even
                 stop good help us},
  label       = {Publisher},
  year        = {2020},
  url         = {https://latex.is.super.omg},
  date        = {2020-04-18},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  I want to cite the publisher and the year \autocite{test:author}.

  I want to cite the publisher and the year \autocite{test:label}.

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: A fancy Publisher 2020//Publisher 2020]

---

A few comments about the code shown in the question

- Bare `.`s should not appear at the end of bibstrings. Instead of `andothers = {et al.},` write

  ```
  \DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
    andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot},
  }
  ```
- `sorting=nyt,` is the default with `style=authoryear,` so need not be given explicitly.
- You can use `\autocite` instead of `\parencite`. `\autocite` can be configured to give parenthetical citations or footnote citations. So it makes it easier to switch styles.
- The option `babel` of `csquotes` was renamed to `autostyle` 10 years ago.